# Check memory free by Unity when loading assetbundles for unload objects from scene in low memory

Tags: unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, unity-webgl

I load assetbundles in scene by Unity3d. I want to know how get memory free from Unity in WebGL? In some moments by application exit with error: The browser could not allocate enough memory for the WebGL content. If you are the developer of this content, try allocating less memory to your WebGL build in the WebGL player settings.

I want remove objects (that loads from assetbundles) if memory low.

Comment: Can't you use the [profiling tools](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html)?

Comment: Yes, I use. My application load many assetbundles with meshes. Its meshes takes many memory. I want remove some objects (that load from assetbundles) when memory low